# maven multiproject dependency error

Tags: java, maven

I've two maven projects A and B. Project A depends on project B, project B has a dependency to XXX.

When I compile (mvn clean install) the project B is working just fine.

But when I compile (mvn clean install) the project A is complaining about an artifact from project B:

[ERROR] Plugin B or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for B: Could not find artifact XXX in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org)

My maven version is 3.3.9 and I'm executing every command from the command line.

Comment: In wich way the project A dependes on project b? Have you link the dependecies of project B in the A's pom?

Comment: are they separate projects or they are included in a "parent" maven project containing both A and B?

Comment: please add your `pom.xml` to the question. If it's too large, create a [MCVE]

Comment: Please check your local maven repository if artifact from project B is there. Just for sure.

Comment: Running this command `mvn dependency:resolve -X` might provide you more information related with the error

Comment: There're no parents. The project A has a dependency on project B and the project B has a dependency on XXX.

Comment: Can you post result of `mvn dependency:tree`